# I am trying to load data into redshift using pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

when i try to load first time pandas able to create the table and load into that, but second time it throwing error like **Relation "mytablename" already exists**

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",sep = "|")
conn = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://uname:pass@xxxxxxxxx.us-east-
1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db')
df.to_sql("my table name",con = conn,if_exists = "append",index = False)
```

sqlalchemy.**version** = '1.1.9'
pandas.**version** = '0.20.3'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: pandas.version = '0.20.3'

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass sqlalchemy engine not the connection object. Try this,

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep = '|')
conn = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://uname:pass@xxxxxxxxx.us-east-
1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db')
df.to_sql('my table name', conn, if_exists = 'append',index = False)
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://uname:pass@xxxxxxxxx.us-east-
1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db') is just engine its not a connection obj

Comment: Oh yes. My bad.